# I downloaded Angry Birds but can't actually find it on my phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace)

Tags: angry-birds

I downloaded Angry Birds onto my phone, but I now actually can't find it anywhere. Does it go into a certain folder?

Comment: you just downloaded the APK? if you did , you need to open it to install it... or try to install it from android market

Comment: how did you download the app? Are you using the Android Market, through 3rd party market, through through GetJar (or other 3rd party providers), or through desktop browser?

Comment: Have you looked at your app drawer?

Answer (score 1):

It may have been downloaded, but has it been installed?

Open up the Market app and click "My Apps". If it isn't listed there - i suggest you reinstall it.

Also, is your device capable of running it?

Comment: Better to look at `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`.

Comment: You're right. Assumed it was obtained via Google Market.